# What does it mean by "Done Diddly doo do"

Tags: slang, urban

What does it mean by "Done Diddly doo do"

I have heard people saying this after a meeting or at the end of the meeting.

> Alright folks we are done diddly doo do.

Comment: You say you have heard "people" saying this. I wonder whether it is actually the same person each time or whether it's been started by a person of influence in an organisation and it's become universal within the organisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diddley-doo, and similar phrases have no meaning at all in this context. They are added humorously (usually but not always after nouns) in order to give an air of familiarity, friendliness, or informality diddley-doo.

If you have ever seen "The Simpsons", the character, Ned Flanders, often adds "diddley", etc. to his sentences.